# Using selenium to attach files and verify file size limit

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a selenium cucumber test to attach files to an email and verify that the file that does not exceed the allotted space. Using the piece of code below I was able to simulate a file attachment, but could not specify a fill size in order to verify that the file does not exceed the limit.

```
WebElement attachFile = driver.findElement(By.id("attachment"));

attachFile.sendKeys("c:\\newfile.txt");
```

Can someone please clarify the issue?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I've attached the file using the above code, but I also need to specify the size of that file in order to test the file size limit of the application.

Comment: Where do you need to provide the size? I believe that once you upload your file and if the file size exceeds the size limit, it will throw you an error message and you could assert that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file, or use an existing one that is over your size rule, and use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("attachment")).sendKeys("<absolutePathToMyFile>");
```

Maybe this is what your looking for?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("attachment")).size()
```

Comment: I'm trying to specify a file size along with the file name, e.g. file.txt, 20MB

Comment: @vslat why don't you just use a test file?

Comment: not every one across the department will have that test file once I create the test.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to simulate the size the same way that I simulated adding the file.

Comment: @vslat The way I understand it, using sendKeys to specify a file is the same as if you broke out of your simulation and selected the file from a dialog. Your not really "simulating" the file selection, the program runs as if a user has done the selection. Therefore you need to have an actual file to perform the test. you won't be able to use a "simulated" file.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say. However, it did appear to have worked, the file appears as attached. I just thought there was a way to specify the size using the same method.

Answer (score 0):

in order to attach a file, you need to copy the files directory into system clipboard using:

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\newfile.txt");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

then you have to click on the attachment element, paste the directory and hit Enter.

```
WebElement attachFile = driver.findElement(By.id("attachment"));
attachFile.click();

Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(500);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```